# Perspective Matrix not drawing object correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

My perspective matrix is doing a weird thing where it makes my 3d pyramid look like a trapezoid.

[This is the effect im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcDGJ.jpg)

[Angle 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eitV8.jpg)

[Angle 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8S6T.jpg)

If I rotate the pyramid this effect is consistent so I don't think it has anything to do with my vertices. What is causing this effect to occur?

Animation Loop:

```
//enables depth testing
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

//creates aspect ratio variable
float aspect = 500.0f / 500.0f;
//enables projection matrix
glm::mat4 pmat = glm::perspective(70.0f, aspect, 0.01f, 1000.0f);
//enables view matrix
glm::vec3 eye(0, -1, 2);
glm::vec3 center(0, 0, 0);
glm::vec3 up(0, 1, 0);
glm::mat4 vmat = glm::lookAt(eye, center, up);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(mWindow)) //animation loop
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glm::mat4 mvp = pmat * vmat * tmat;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uTransform, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvp));
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberofshapes; i++)
    {
        glBindVertexArray(shapes[i].vao);
        glDrawArrays(shapes[i].drawtype, 0, shapes[i].numOfvertices);
    }
    if (w == true) {
        tmat = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.001f, 0.0f)) * tmat;
    }if (a == true) {
        tmat = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(-0.001f, 0.0f, 0.0f)) * tmat;
    }if (s == true) {
        tmat = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -0.001f, 0.0f)) * tmat;
    }if (d == true) {
        tmat = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.001f, 0.0f, 0.0f)) * tmat;
    }if (r == true) {
        tmat = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(0.1f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)) * tmat;
    }
    glfwSwapBuffers(mWindow);
    counter += 1;
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Vertex Arrays:

```
vertex vertices[] = {
    mkVert(0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    mkVert(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    mkVert(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
};

//SECOND OBJECT
vertex vertices2[] = {
    mkVert(0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    mkVert(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    mkVert(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
};

//THIRD OBJECT
vertex vertices3[] = {
    mkVert(0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    mkVert(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    mkVert(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
};
vertex vertices4[] = {
    mkVert(0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    mkVert(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    mkVert(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
};
```

Just fyi my window is 500x500, I dont know if that would cause this effect.

Comment: Do you have any additonal pictures (or, ideally, a gif) of the pyramid rotating? As-is, it's not obvious that there's anything wrong with the image.

Comment: [`glm::perspective()`'s `fovy` parameter should be in radians](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00169.html#gac3613dcb6c6916465ad5b7ad5a786175), at least in in the current GLM version (0.9.8).

Comment: Well i dont know how to make a gif but ill include a couple more images.

Comment: You're looking at your pyramid from down under… ;)

Comment: This looks like a perfectly good pyramid seen from below.

Comment: So you're saying that the effect is caused by the angle that the pyramid is being looked at and not the perspective matrix?

Comment: You are looking at the pyramid from below and because you're using perspective, foreshortening is causing the base to appear as a trapezoid rather than a square.

Answer (score 0):

Your camera is pointing at your pyramid from below. I guess your brain expected to look at it from above!? Especially with just a wireframe, this can get confusing. So here's a GIF of a pyramid being looked at from below:

[image]